# Format string using json

Tags: python, json

Here is a file called `subtitles.ass`. If you have a look at it, you will find I define `{font_size}` and `{sentence[0}`. Obviously I want to format them with my input data.

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by FFmpeg/Lavc57.107.100
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: sorry,Arial,{font_size},&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,1,2,10,10,12,1


[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.97,0:00:01.50,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[0]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.11,0:00:04.39,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[1]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.18,0:00:07.26,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[2]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.26,0:00:09.91,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[3]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:10.00,0:00:11.26,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[4]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.63,0:00:12.70,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[5]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:13.61,0:00:16.01,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[6]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:18.08,0:00:19.60,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[7]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:19.60,0:00:21.60,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[8]}
```

First I read data from `subtitles.ass`.

```
with open(subtitles_file, 'r') as file:
    subtitles = file.read()
```

And now input data comes.

```
{
  "font_size": "47",
  "sentences": [
   ....
  ]
}
```

Finally I want to format subtitles with above json data. Simply, I want to replace {font_size} with 47. `data` is above json.

```
subtitles.format(data.get('font_size'), data.get('sentences'))
```

However I got an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "iemoji.py", line 17, in 
>       subtitles.format(data.get('font_size'), data.get('sentences'))
>   KeyError: 'font_size'

## EDIT for `data`

I load data like this.

```
data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Can you post the dictionary contained in `data`?

Comment: If the thing you show after "And now input data comes" is your `data`, then you don't get that exception, you get the string `'47'`. And even if that _isn't_ your `data`, `data.get('font_size')` still isn't going to raise that exception, it's going to return `None`—that's the whole point of using `get` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Obvisouly `data` is json data.

Comment: I am not an English native speaker. If you don't know what I am asking, you can comment then I will update my question. Thanks.

Comment: I think I've guessed what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure. Read my answer, and if I guessed wrong, I'll delete it and try again.

Comment: Yes I want to do like this. You are so kind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CoXier: Please see my answer if that solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to unpack the dictionary inside `format` function to get key value pairs.

try:

```
subtitles.format(**data)
```

This is exactly what format_map is for.

```
subtitles.format_map(data)
```

working example:

```
import json

subtitles = """[Script Info]
; Script generated by FFmpeg/Lavc57.107.100
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: sorry,Arial,{font_size},&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,1,2,10,10,12,1


[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.97,0:00:01.50,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[0]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.11,0:00:04.39,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[1]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:05.18,0:00:07.26,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[2]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.26,0:00:09.91,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[3]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:10.00,0:00:11.26,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[4]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.63,0:00:12.70,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[5]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:13.61,0:00:16.01,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[6]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:18.08,0:00:19.60,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[7]}
Dialogue: 0,0:00:19.60,0:00:21.60,sorry,,0,0,0,,{sentence[8]}"""

data_str = """{
    "font_size": "47",
    "sentence": [
        "sample sentence0",
        "sample sentence1",
        "sample sentence2",
        "sample sentence3",
        "sample sentence4",
        "sample sentence5",
        "sample sentence6",
        "sample sentence7",
        "sample sentence8",
        "sample sentence9"
    ]
}"""

data = json.loads(data_str)
print(subtitles.format(**data))#or
#print(subtitles.format_map(data))
```

Comment: Why does your example use `format_map()` ? 'str' object has no attribute 'format_map'

Comment: It was suggested by @abarnert and I was on mobile sou couldn't test it. Just read the docs and updated. Reverted the update till I try it.

Comment: I Checked and it's there in python 3.5+

Answer (score 1):

The error here isn't coming from `data.get`, but from `font_size`.

When you use a named parameter in a [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) string, you have to provide a keyword value with a matching name. But you're only providing positional values, so there's nothing that matches.

You *could* fix this by doing something clumsy like:

```
subtitles.format(font_size=data.get('font_size'),
                 sentences=data.get('sentences'))
```

But really, this is exactly what [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) is for:

```
subtitles.format_map(data)
```

---

For future reference, it's a lot easier to debug things like this if you (temporarily) break up the expression, so you can see exactly which part causes the exception:

```
font_size = data.get('font_size')
sentences = data.get('sentences')
subtitles.format(font_size, sentences)
```

Then you'll see that it's the third line, not the first, that's raising the `KeyError`, and it'll be a lot easier to figure out why.

---

Finally, I'm not sure why you're using `data.get('font_size')` instead of just `data['font_size']`. If you're doing it to get a default value instead of a `KeyError` if you left the font size out of the data dict, you almost certainly don't want that default value to be `None`, do you? Anyway, if there *is* a good reason for it, even that can be simplified: turn `data` into a `collections.defaultdict(lambda: whatever-default-value-you-want)`, and then any missing key will have that default value. (Even if you use it with `format_map`.)

Comment: Do you forget `}` ?

Comment: @CoXier Thanks; fixed.

Comment: There is KeyError: 'font_size'.  subtitles.format({'font_size': data.get('font_size'),
                  'sentences': data.get('sentences')})

Comment: @CoXier Oops, those were supposed to be keyword arguments, not members of a dict; fixed. But anyway, I said that version is clumsy, and it's obviously a lot more verbose (and easy to get wrong, as I keep proving) than just using `format_map`, so why not do that?

Comment: @Rahul: As the linked docs explain, `format(**data)` is nearly the same thing as `format_map(data)`. The differences are that the former requires every key in `data` to be a valid identifier, and that it forces Python to make a copy of `data` in case it's some other mapping besides a `dict`, and that it's a tiny bit less clear (you have to understand keyword splatting to read it). If you use `format(**data)` it will of course work in this case, because all of the keys (at least in the OP's examples) are valid identifiers, but why?